# Debian 6.0: install mysqlnd_ms

Tags: debian-squeeze, php, pecl

I'm trying to install mysqlnd_ms on my new server (Debian 6.0 i386).

To do so, I've tried as follow :

1. I install `php5-5.4.0-3` and `php5-mysqlnd` by testing repo.
2. After read this link:1, I try to install `mysqlnd_ms` by pecl so I install `php5-dev` and `php5-pear`

After that I try `pecl install mysqlnd_ms` and I have this :

```
 downloading mysqlnd_ms-1.2.2.tgz ...
 Starting to download mysqlnd_ms-1.2.2.tgz (337,534 bytes)
 .............................done: 337,534 bytes
 ERROR: bad md5sum for file /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/package.xml
```

It's the same issue as this bug repport link:2.

So I've decided to do the job by myself and follow the same process than pecl (download, compile, install) link:3 :

1. `pecl download mysqlnd_ms`
2. After untar the source, `phpize`
3. `./configure`
4. `make test` and I have an error because of missing `ext/mysqlnd/*`
5. I get those files from php-src from link:4
6. `make test` again and new issue :

   ```
   error: ./php_mysqlnd_config.h: No such file or directory
   ```
7. I found link:5 and link:6 on the intraweb . So I try `./configure --enable-mysqlnd`. After get this :

   ```
   configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-mysqlnd
   ```

   I try `./configure -h` :

   ```
   Optional Features:
    --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
    --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
    --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
    --enable-mysqlnd-ms           Enable mysqlnd_ms support
    --enable-mysqlnd-ms-table-filter   Enable support for table filter in mysqlnd_ms      (EXPERIMENTAL - do not use!)
    --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
    --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=yes]
    --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                     optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
    --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)
   ```

   There is no such parameter to configure the build.I'm stuck right now.

Is there a way to install `mysqlnd_ms` on Debian with `PHP5-5.4.0-3` ? or with a previous version of PHP ? In case of previous version of PHP, how can I get this version and all linked composants ?

Thank you for your help.

All links here (due to serverfault spam prevention limitation) : [gist](https://gist.github.com/2225105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem(s) - turns out there were two issues here...

### 1. bad md5sum for file /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/package.xml

> ERROR: bad md5sum for file /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/package.xml

This was as described, turns out in pecl packages there's a package.xml that lists the md5 value of all files in the tar. I solved this by downloading the pecl package and replacing the package.xml md5 with the correct value (using md5sum package.xml on the file itself). Steps:

```
sudo pecl download mysqlnd_ms
```

Then extract the tar, run the following on package.xml (which was in the root of the zip file, not the folder with everything else)

```
md5sum package.xml
```

And updating the contents of package.xml (line 458 for me) so it reads the correct md5, for me it was:

```
<file md5sum="f0051920d77ae99ba5a3fe6c3bcaa402" name="package.xml" role="src" />
```

Re-tar the package again, and you'll see running the installation gets you further..

```
sudo pecl install mysqlnd_ms-1.3.2.tar
```

But not all the way, leading me to the next issue you and I both faced...

### 2. error: ./php_mysqlnd_config.h: No such file or directory

I was using the standard Ubuntu 12.04 PHP 5.3 from the default apt-get repos, which does not come with the mysql native driver support out of the box, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php.

So I removed the current PHP install, downloaded the PHP source and compiled / installed with the all important configure flags --enable-pdo --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd

There was a lot of dependencies missing from my default install to get everything I wanted, some of which might not matter to you, but here's my full package dependencies install and configure commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libbz2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg62-dev libxpm-dev libfreetype6-dev libt1-dev libmcrypt-dev libmhash-dev libxslt1-dev

./configure --enable-fpm --enable-soap --enable-calendar --enable-ftp --enable-libxml --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --enable-zend-multibyte --enable-zip --with-zlib --with-mcrypt --enable-pdo --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-gd

make test

make install
```

Now running the installation works fine for me:

```
sudo pecl install mysqlnd_ms-1.3.2.tar
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Hi Mark,
I did the same thing to fix the problem.
Download the source for php-5.4.2 from php.net.
Then `./configure --mysql (default is mysqlnd) --with-pear`
`make`
`make test`
`make install`
Finally I used, as you, `sudo pecl install mysql_ms-1.3.2.tar`.
Thank you for you feedback !